# Fix app position in Task View in Win 10

Tags: windows-10, task-view

In Win 10, there's a task view button that lets you switch between desktops and view your currently open apps. Since I've started using desktops, I only have a handful of apps per desktop, so I'd really like them to stay in a fixed position rather than rearranging based on which one was opened last (current behavior). Is there a setting anywhere to configure this?

Even though I may only have 4 apps on a desktop, using task view can be disorienting because the apps are always rearranged differently, and I have to pause to find the right one :/

Comment: The list is ordered by last focused. I don't think this behaviour is configurable.

Comment: Hmm that sucks!